# Multiple INSERT in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I feel like this is probably a really easy issue, but I can't quite find what I'm looking for. I'm new to stored procedure, but I'm trying to create a stored procedure to somewhat automate something I'll be doing every year. I've got some variables, then I've got a WITH statement. I would like to use the table/view (?) I've created with the WITH statement to insert multiple rows into another table. I've got something like this:

```
DECLARE @YEAR INT SET @YEAR = 2018

-- MOD
DECLARE @NA_MOD FLOAT SET @NA_MOD = 0.69;
DECLARE @EA_MOD FLOAT SET @EA_MOD = 0.13;
DECLARE @AP_MOD FLOAT SET @AP_MOD = 0.11;
DECLARE @LA_MOD FLOAT SET @LA_MOD = 0.07;

WITH MODTARGS AS (
SELECT  YearTarg * @NA_MOD 'YTargNA', YearTarg * @EA_MOD 'YTargEA', YearTarg * @AP_MOD 'YTargAP', YearTarg * @LA_MOD 'YTargLA', 
        JanTarg * @NA_MOD 'JanTargNA', JanTarg * @EA_MOD 'JanTargEA', JanTarg * @AP_MOD 'JanTargAP', JanTarg * @LA_MOD 'JanTargLA',
        FebTarg * @NA_MOD 'FebTargNA', FebTarg * @EA_MOD 'FebTargEA', FebTarg * @AP_MOD 'FebTargAP', FebTarg * @LA_MOD 'FebTargLA',
        MarTarg * @NA_MOD 'MarTargNA', MarTarg * @EA_MOD 'MarTargEA', MarTarg * @AP_MOD 'MarTargAP', MarTarg * @LA_MOD 'MarTargLA',
        AprTarg * @NA_MOD 'AprTargNA', AprTarg * @EA_MOD 'AprTargEA', AprTarg * @AP_MOD 'AprTargAP', AprTarg * @LA_MOD 'AprTargLA',
        MayTarg * @NA_MOD 'MayTargNA', MayTarg * @EA_MOD 'MayTargEA', MayTarg * @AP_MOD 'MayTargAP', MayTarg * @LA_MOD 'MayTargLA',
        JunTarg * @NA_MOD 'JunTargNA', JunTarg * @EA_MOD 'JunTargEA', JunTarg * @AP_MOD 'JunTargAP', JunTarg * @LA_MOD 'JunTargLA',
        JulTarg * @NA_MOD 'JulTargNA', JulTarg * @EA_MOD 'JulTargEA', JulTarg * @AP_MOD 'JulTargAP', JulTarg * @LA_MOD 'JulTargLA',
        AugTarg * @NA_MOD 'AugTargNA', AugTarg * @EA_MOD 'AugTargEA', AugTarg * @AP_MOD 'AugTargAP', AugTarg * @LA_MOD 'AugTargLA',
        SepTarg * @NA_MOD 'SepTargNA', SepTarg * @EA_MOD 'SepTargEA', SepTarg * @AP_MOD 'SepTargAP', SepTarg * @LA_MOD 'SepTargLA',
        OctTarg * @NA_MOD 'OctTargNA', OctTarg * @EA_MOD 'OctTargEA', OctTarg * @AP_MOD 'OctTargAP', OctTarg * @LA_MOD 'OctTargLA',
        NovTarg * @NA_MOD 'NovTargNA', NovTarg * @EA_MOD 'NovTargEA', NovTarg * @AP_MOD 'NovTargAP', NovTarg * @LA_MOD 'NovTargLA',
        DecTarg * @NA_MOD 'DecTargNA', DecTarg * @EA_MOD 'DecTargEA', DecTarg * @AP_MOD 'DecTargAP', DecTarg * @LA_MOD 'DecTargLA'
FROM    TRACKINGTABLE1
WHERE   Application = 'MOD'
        AND Year = @YEAR)

-- INSERT NA    
INSERT  INTO TRACKINGTABLE2
SELECT  'MOD', @YEAR, 'NA', YTargNA, JanTargNA, FebTargNA, MarTargNA, AprTargNA, MayTargNA, JunTargNA, JulTargNA,
        AugTargNA, SepTargNA, OctTargNA, NovTargNA, DecTargNA
FROM    MODTARGS

-- INSERT AP
INSERT  INTO TRACKINGTABLE2
SELECT  'MOD', @YEAR, 'AP', YTargAP, JanTargAP, FebTargAP, MarTargAP, AprTargAP, MayTargAP, JunTargAP, JulTargAP,
        AugTargAP, SepTargAP, OctTargAP, NovTargAP, DecTargAP
FROM    MODTARGS
```

However, when I try to run this, I get an "Invalid object name MODTARGS" error for the second INSERT. I've tried various combinations of using GO, of putting a comma or a semicolon after the first INSERT, and nothing has worked. Is this possible? Am I making a really simple syntax error?

Comment: A `CTE` can only followed by a `SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE`. You can't insert from the `CTE` twice, which mean `INSERT  INTO TRACKINGTABLE2` will fail. You can declare a table to store the data or create a `#Temp` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CTE is only valid for the statement directly following, so in your second `INSERT` it isn't "known" any more.

You could use a temporary table or a table variable instead.

But it seems like you can do that even easier, all in one statement, if you cross join that `'NA'` and `'AP'` to the CTE.

```
WITH modtargs AS (
...)
INSERT INTO trackingtable2
SELECT  'MOD',
        @year,
        x.x,
        ma.ytargna,
        ma.jantargna,
        ...
        ma.dectargna
        FROM modtargs ma
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'NA' x
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT 'AP' x) x;
```

By the way, it advisable to explicitly mention the targeted columns in an `INSERT`.

Comment: Thank you! Literally just now I tinkered with using a TEMP table and that did the trick. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Adding `GO` or `;` does not make sense, because the `CTE` can only followed by a `SELECT, INSERT, DELETE` and used just once which make your 2nd insert never work.

A possible soulution is to decalre a table (`DECLARE @T TABLE (...)`) or use a `#Temp` table to store your data then insert it as many you want.

Comment: Thank you! Literally just now I tinkered with using a TEMP table and that did the trick. Thanks again!